# Looking up a vertex using a unique property

Tags: orientdb

I am a newby to Orient DB.

Today I got an Orient graph/doc database up and created various vertices and edges. My primary client is from the Java programming language, and I was able to look up a vertex through its RID.  So RID-based lookup works well.
Unfortunately, this does not help me. I need to look up a vertex by its
unique label.

Each label associated with a vertex will be unique.
So I want to lookup a vertex by this unique label. To me, this seems
an extremely  basic operation for a graph database. I have now spent several
hours looking for an example where such a lookup is performed, but 
without success.

Here is another way to express my use case...

While my use case doesn't really involve Twitter, my use case
is still easily expressed as a Twitter use case. That is, each
vertex will be associated with some Twitter hash tag, and I want to be able
to lookup a vertex by its associated (and unique) hash tag.

Any advice on how to do this, particularly through a Java-based 
client would be much appreciated.

Note: this is a core use case, and should be documented. I cannot find any documentation on this. Either it is missing, or I cannot find it. 
In either case, I need help, and help would very much be appreciated.

Note: I have also searched through the test cases on GitHub trying to find this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the documentation here?

http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Performance-Tuning-Graph.html#use-indexes-to-lookup-vertices-by-an-id

Comment: Thank you! That is just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `g.getVertices("Class.property","value");`